# what actually happens if we try to determine the size of an array after passing it to a function

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>
void length(int arr[])
{
 int len=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
 printf("%d",len);
} 

main()
{
 int arr[]={4,5,6,3,21,9,3,8};
 length(arr);
}
```

In this code the answer is always 2. I am unable to understand why.Is it necessary to send the size always.

Comment: Try not dividing it. Maybe it will be 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you cannot pass whole array to the called function, because in that case it may take huge stack space, since, as far as I know, arguments passed to functions are stored on the stack.

Hence when you try to pass the array to the function, the **array name decays into a pointer to first element of the array** because array is stored in contiguous memory locations, and therefore you just need to know address of first element.

As already pointed out by *@John Zwinck*, the exact reason for you always getting output as `2` may be that you are on a `64-bit` system.

On a 64-bit system/compiler the size of a pointer is `8 bytes` (simply because the system can access `2^64` addresses and hence requires 8 bytes to store them) and size of `int` is `4 bytes`.

Comment: Do you have a reference to back up the "because" claim?

Comment: No it was my calculated guess. Because an array of (say) 100 statically allocated integers cannot be allocated anywhere in C's memory map other than in stack. Please comment if you think otherwise.

Comment: I'd say it is up to you to provide proof for claims you make in your answers. It is plausible, but you are stating it as a fact.

Comment: You are right. So, I have tried changing my wording.

Answer (score 1):

It is always 2 because `arr` is a pointer and you're on a 64-bit system.  And `int` is 32 bits on your system.  Divide them out, and you get 2.

You simply cannot get the length of an array like this, because it decays to a pointer when passed to a function.  You need to pass the size explicitly, or use a sentinel to designate the end of the list (like null-terminated strings do).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's necessary to send the size always, `sizeof(arr)` reports the size of a pointer:

> **Q**: Why doesn't sizeof properly report the size of an array when the array is a parameter to a function? I have a test routine
>
> f(char a[10])   {       int i = sizeof(a);      printf("%d\n", i);  }
>
> and it prints 4, not 10.
>
> **A**: The compiler pretends that the array parameter was declared as a pointer (that is, in the example, as char *a; see question 6.4), and
>   sizeof reports the size of the pointer. See also questions 1.24 and
>   7.28.
>
> References: H&S Sec. 7.5.2 p. 195

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html

Or you can use an extra first element containing the size:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void length(int arr[])
{
    int len = arr[-1];

    printf("%d", len);
} 

int main(void)
{
    int arr[]={0,4,5,6,3,21,9,3,8}; /* Note first element = 0 */

    arr[0] = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) - 1;
    length(arr + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To avoid negative index: in `main()`: `...; length(arr); ...` and in `length(int arr[])`: `int len = arr[0]; arr++; ...`.

Comment: Passing `arr + 1` allows using the real array in the function.

Comment: Your intentions are good. I just suggested another method because some programmers may not like/understand negative index. :-)

Comment: True, but then you need to use constructions like `for (i = 1; ..)` (base 1 instead of base 0)

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?